# Traits collecting different pins and timers

Tags: rust, arduino, embedded, traits

I am using [avr-hal](https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal) to control the rgb for a LED on the digital output on a arduino uno and  use `set_duty` for a variety of TimerPWM and PDs to change the colors. Since this is working fine and has the same function call everywhere I would now like to combine the functionality for every pin into a single function.
But I am not able to find a trait combining the arbitrary Timers and PDs into one type, just having `pin.set_duty(duty:u8)` available.

How could one combine the two implementations of `Blinks` into fitting for both types: `Pin<PwmOutput<Timer0Pwm>, PD6>`and `Pin<PwmOutput<Timer2Pwm>, PD3>`

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use arduino_hal::hal::port::{PD3, PD6};
use arduino_hal::pac::TC0;
use arduino_hal::port::mode::{Analog, Input, Output, PwmOutput};
use arduino_hal::port::Pin;
use arduino_hal::prelude::*;
use arduino_hal::simple_pwm::{IntoPwmPin, Timer0Pwm, Timer2Pwm};
use arduino_hal::{DefaultClock, Peripherals, Pins, Usart};
use panic_halt as _;

trait Blinks {
    fn blink(&mut self);
}

impl Blinks for Pin<PwmOutput<Timer0Pwm>, PD6> {
    fn blink(&mut self) {
        self.set_duty(200);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(100);
        self.set_duty(0);
    }
}

impl Blinks for Pin<PwmOutput<Timer2Pwm>, PD3> {
    fn blink(&mut self) {
        self.set_duty(200);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(100);
        self.set_duty(0);
    }
}

#[arduino_hal::entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);

    let mut pwm_timer0 = arduino_hal::simple_pwm::Timer0Pwm::new(
        dp.TC0,
        arduino_hal::simple_pwm::Prescaler::Prescale64,
    );
    let mut pwm_timer2 = arduino_hal::simple_pwm::Timer2Pwm::new(
        dp.TC2,
        arduino_hal::simple_pwm::Prescaler::Prescale64,
    );

    let mut red = pins.d6.into_output().into_pwm(&mut pwm_timer0);
    let mut blue = pins.d3.into_output().into_pwm(&mut pwm_timer2);

    red.enable();
    blue.enable();

    loop {
        red.blink();
        blue.blink();
    }
}
```

I already tried to implement the trait for `for Pin<PinOps + arduino_hal::prelude::_embedded_hal_Pwm>`but then  I am depending on the trait  `Dynamic` and would loose the ability to set duty directly via `set_duty(duty:u8)`.

I also tried relying on `PwmPinOps` but then I am tightly bound to the timers again:

```rust
impl<TC, P> Blinks for P
where
    P: PwmPinOps<TC, Duty = u8>,
{
     fn blink(&mut self) {
        self.set_duty(200);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(100);
        self.set_duty(0);
     }
}

// error[E0207]: the type parameter `TC` is not constrained by the impl // trait, self type, or predicates
//   --> src/main.rs:87:6
//    |
// 87 | impl<TC, P> Blinks for P
//    |      ^^ unconstrained type parameter
```

Comment: Since `set_duty` is from the [`PwmPinOps`](https://rahix.github.io/avr-hal/atmega_hal/simple_pwm/trait.PwmPinOps.html) trait it seems logical to use that trait as bound when implementing, can't test right now since I don't have access to a rust compiler.

Comment: I did try this, but then TC gets in my way. See my last edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `impl` that the `set_duty` method itself belongs to](https://rahix.github.io/avr-hal/src/avr_hal_generic/simple_pwm.rs.html#63) is defined like this:

```
impl<TC, PIN: PwmPinOps<TC>> Pin<mode::PwmOutput<TC>, PIN> {
   // ...
}
```

This generic `impl` matches any `Pin` whose mode is a `PwmOutput`. You could implement your `Blinks` trait for the same set of types, like this:

```
impl<TC, PIN: PwmPinOps<TC>> Blinks for Pin<mode::PwmOutput<TC>, PIN> {
    fn blink(&mut self) {
        self.set_duty(200);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(100);
        self.set_duty(0);
    }
}
```

This trait would therefore be implemented for any pin type that could support the `set_duty` method, which should include both `Pin<PwmOutput<Timer0Pwm>, PD6>` and `Pin<PwmOutput<Timer2Pwm>, PD3>`, so your `red` and `blue` variables should both still support it.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem and also gave much valuable Information how to tackle this situation in the future.